# How to get error line number when using IExceptionHandlerPathFeature

Tags: exception, .net-6.0

I am testing a custom error page with IExceptionHandlerPathFeature (see test code in "CODE SEGMENT" section). In the stack trace, I can see the code line number where the exception was triggered.

**I would like to know how to extract the line number from the stack trace without having to parse the large block of text. What methods I could use to get the line number?**

**TEST ENVIRONMENT**

App Type:     ASP .NET 6 with Razor pages

IDE:          VS 2022

Dev Machine:  Windows 11

**CODE SEGMENT**

```
public class ErrorHandlerModel : PageModel
{
    private string _envName;

    public ExceptionDetailsModel ExceptionInfo { get; set; }
    public ErrorHandlerModel(IWebHostEnvironment webEnv)
    {
        _envName = webEnv.EnvironmentName;
    }
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        var exceptionFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

        if (exceptionFeature != null)
        {
            string reqId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
            ExceptionInfo = new ExceptionDetailsModel(reqId);

            if (HttpContext.Response.StatusCode != 0)
                ExceptionInfo.HttpStatus = HttpContext.Response.StatusCode.ToString();

            ExceptionInfo.ErrorMessage = exceptionFeature.Error.Message;
            ExceptionInfo.StackTrace = exceptionFeature.Error.StackTrace.ToString();
            ExceptionInfo.Route = exceptionFeature.Path;

        }

        if (_envName.ToLower().IndexOf("develop") >= 0)
        {
            TempData["show_error_details"] = "yes";
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["show_error_details"] = "no";
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```